# Cannot get data from sqlite database with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I used the following code to get items from sqlite3 database

```
def get(self, item_name, attrs=True): #get attr from item and return as dict, if attr==True: get all items
    conn = self.conn
    if attrs: #all
        return conn.execute('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE __item_key__ = "%s";' %(self.table, item_name))
    else:
        command = 'SELECT '
        for attr in attrs:
            command+= attr+' '
        command+='FROM %s WHERE __item_key__ = "%s";' %(self.table, item_name)
        return conn.execute(command)

print(get('name1'))
```

the code print the following:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor at 0x213d4c0f490>
```

instead of the values from the table.

When I try this:

```
get('name1')[0]
```

it returns:

```
TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable
```

Full code:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

import sqlite3 as sql

class db:

    '''
    This class turns dicts into sqlite databases
    and output sqlite databases as dicts
    '''

    def __init__(self, db_name, table_name): #open or create a database
        conn = sql.connect(db_name).cursor()
        self.table = table_name
        self.conn = conn

    def create(self, table_name, cols):
        command = "CREATE TABLE %s(_item_key_ TEXT," % table_name
        for key, value in cols.items():
            command+="%s %s," %(key, value)
        command=command[:-1]
        command+=");"
        self.conn.execute(command)
        self.table = table_name

    def get(self, item_name, attrs=True): #get attr from item and return as dict, if attr==True: get all items
        conn = self.conn
        if attrs: #all
            return conn.execute('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE _item_key_ = "%s";' %(self.table, item_name))
        else:
            command = 'SELECT '
            for attr in attrs:
                if type(attr) == str:
                    attr = '"'+attr+'"'
                command+= str(attr)+' '
            command+='FROM %s WHERE _item_key_ = "%s";' %(self.table, item_name)
            return conn.execute(command).fetchall()

    def change(self, item_name, attrs): #change certain attrs of item
        command = 'UPDATE %s SET ' %self.table
        for key, value in attrs:
            command += '%s=%s,'%(key, value)
        command = command[:-1]+' WHERE _item_name_ = "'+item_name+'";'

    def add(self, item_name, attrs): #add an item with attrs to database
        command = 'INSERT INTO %s VALUES ("%s",' %(self.table, item_name)
        for attr in attrs:
            if type(attr) == str:
                attr = '"'+attr+'"'
            command += str(attr)+','
        command = command[:-1]+');'
        #print(command)
        self.conn.execute(command)

    def close(self): #close database
        self.conn.close()
```

The table is supposed to look like the following (although I never saw it):

```
__item_name__     A      B
---------------------------
'name1'          123    'hi'
'name2'          344    'bye'
```

Does anyone know how this works?

edit: I realized some bugs in create() and add(). However, after fixing some stuff it still prints the same thing in get().

Comment: Print your "command" (query)

Comment: print(get('name1')) doesnt work and prints the same thing

Comment: I means: print(command) ... I check my code and after each self.conn.execute(xxx) I do self.conn.commit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns that no cursor object found.
If you want to get the results you need to add these lines:

```
cur = conn.cursor()  # create a cursor to your connection
cur.execute(your_query)  # execute your query
results = cur.fetchall()  # fetch the results
```

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to iterate over the cursor after `results = cur.fetchall()`:

```
for row in results:
    A = row[0]
    B = row[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Should revise all code and implement this self.conn.commit() after self.conn.execute(---).

```
self.conn.execute(command)
self.conn.commit() #<--- THIS NEW line, to after .execute()
self.table = table_name
```